# Why is there a need for local DNS servers?

Tags: dns

I understand that local DNS servers do some caching, which can help reduce traffic in root/TLD/authoritative DNS servers. However, I do not understand why the final hosts can't ask for addresses themselves, instead of through local DNS servers. Hosts could also do the caching themselves, which loses somewhat in terms of saving network traffic, but increases privacy.

Is some kind of clearance or other technical requirement needed to request addresses to a DNS server? (e.g., to request addresses to root servers)

Or is it just customary for us to request records through a local DNS server, and we could do it directly if we wanted to? (by running DNS in our own computer)

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but you can certainly install a local caching nameserver on any computer, to have it resolve all names locally. See `unbound` for example that is very install to use, and even `stubby` as an extension of it. Note also that browsers now do DNS over HTTPS themselves, bypassing (specially Firefox) any local DNS setup and nameservers.

Comment: I see! Makes sense. Thank you for the answer!